# I don't understand why the slides in my carousel aren't visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to Javascript and I don't have a clue why my CarouFredSel plugin's slides are invisible... I've been trying to get it to work for hours now with no success.

I made content, put it in a container, then launched the carouFredSel function on the container. And now the content in the slides aren't appearing.

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="carousel-wrapper">
            <div class="slide" id="slide-1">
                <div class="slider-container">
                    <div class="content-container">
                           <h1>Header</h1>
                           <p>Paragraph text.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide" id="slide-2">
                <div class="slider-container">
                    <div class="content-container">
                        <h1>Header</h1>
                        <p>Paragraph text.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide" id="slide-3">
                <div class="slider-container">
                    <div class="content-container">
                        <h1>Header</h1>
                        <p>Paragraph text.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide" id="slide-4">
                <div class="slider-container">
                    <div class="content-container">
                        <h1>Header</h1>
                        <p>Paragraph text.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide" id="slide-5">
                <div class="slider-container">
                    <div class="content-container">
                        <h1>Header</h1>
                        <p>Paragraph text.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

                // Using default configuration
                $("#carousel-wrapper").carouFredSel();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.slide {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}

.content-container {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 23%;
    margin-top: 197px;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

The function is definitely executing and refreshing slides but the content is invisible. Help is muchly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You sure it's invisible, and not just hidden? Those margins on `.content-container` look suspicious. Have you used your browser's dev tools to see what's going on?

Comment: Unless you create a [mcve], chances are nobody here will help you. Perhaps link your resources absolutely, not relatively? Your example won't work unless you provide real links to those resources.

Comment: instead of $(document).ready(function() , try $(window).load(function(){})

Comment: Andrei I don't understand how to do that... I've tried to put my CSS and HTML here I don't know how to create a live example.

chazsolo I didn't mean invisible as in a physical state I meant the content that should be showing isn't. In inspect element the content is there but it isn't showing.

Comment: TripsLeft my function is executing so there isn't any need to change how the function is loaded is there?

Comment: ok, just letting you know I had the same problem & that fixed it for me on that project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing

```
.content-container {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 23%;
  margin-top: 197px;
}
```

seems to fix it. Especially the `margin-left` part. Try not to use CSS properties if you don't fully understand their context.
Here's a <kbd>[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/u411fvd8/1/)</kbd>.

Comment: Andrei this worked, could you explain this a bit more for me?

When designing slides I designed them as one class, and the percentage of 23% worked as it was 23% of the screen (Im using 100% width for the carousel) so why when the carousel is executing does it completely make it go farther right?

Comment: This [write-up](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) will explain it better than I could.

Comment: Andrei is there anyway I can contact you to ask you some questions? I haven't seen an inboxing feature on this site anywhere :/

Comment: @FelipeWarrener If you use the contact form of my website, which is linked in my SO profile), you'll be sending me an email.

Comment: Done, don't know if I typed my email correctly or not though lol

Comment: I replied and haven't got a delivery failure so I'm guessing it's all good.

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#carousel-wrapper").carouFredSel();
});
```

Comment: TripsLeft, the code you posted is already included in the project.

Comment: That's not the problem. it works fine on ready, too. [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/u411fvd8/)

Comment: Thanks for following up, was just a suggestion, as it has helped me in the past